# Using Microprofile with Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

from Quarkus documentation I can read "Quarkus is made of ... Hibernate, RESTEasy, Eclipse Microprofile, etc.". I have an application which uses Thorntail stack so it's compatible with Eclipse Microprofile. Is the MicroProfile stack compatible with Quarkus's stack ? Should I change just the dependencies name, leaving the code untouched ?
Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of parts of Microprofile incorporated in Quarkus - see the extensions https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/master/extensions that start with `smallrye-`. I would suggest you try and use those dependencies in your project (along with the proper Quarkus configuration obviously) and see how it goes. If you have problems don't  hesitate to reach out :)

Comment: Quarkus implements all MicroProfile 2.2 specs, and also has an implementation of the draft MicroProfile Reactive Messaging" spec. I think I'll write up a blog post that maps MicroProfile specs to Quarkus extensions.

Comment: Thanks! that sounds an exciting news! So being MicroProfile compatible I will be able to switch from another Microprofile implementation to Quarkus quite easily!

Comment: That's the idea!

Comment: Carla, this may help: https://microprofile.io/2019/04/22/quarkus-microprofile-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Thanks again for the quick turnaround!

Comment: @JohnClingan maybe that should be an answer so future viewers don't have to go through the comments to find it?

Comment: Carla, check [this blog post](https://microprofile.io/2019/04/22/quarkus-microprofile-cheat-sheet/) that maps MicroProfile specs to Quarkus maven dependencies.

Comment: Agreed. Created an answer.

Comment: @Carla Can you upvote the answer if you think answers your question? Thanks.

Comment: This post can help you

[Part1: Migrating Java applications to Quarkus: Lessons learned](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/12/migrating-java-applications-to-quarkus-lessons-learned/)

[Part 2: Migrating Java applications to Quarkus: Before and after](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/05/13/migrating-java-applications-to-quarkus-part-2-before-and-after/)